# Can I get the service account of a cloud sql instance before create it via terraform

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql_instance" {
   ...
   ...
   replica_configuration {
    dump_file_path  = var.database_dump_gs_url
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to create a cloud sql instance with a dump from Google Cloud Storage Bucket, so I should add the permission storage.objects.get to Cloud Sql instance service account, but I can not get the service account email before the creation of the instance

Comment: Indeed, the dump_file_path should point to a GCS bucket that is accessible to the service account of the Cloud SQL instance...which is not yet created... 